# I am trying to make a distro. Is there a possible way I can change “Try Ubuntu” button time something else?

Tags: boot, iso

I am trying to make a distro.

Is there a possible way I can change “Try Ubuntu” and “Install Ubuntu” in the live iso, to something else? The buttons you press, I want to change what they say. I want to change the button text.

Does anybody know how I can do that?

Comment: what application are you using to customize the ISO?? I have done in the past using CUBIC..

Comment: you mean not in the grub menu options? so whats the case.. which version of Ubuntu you want to customize..

Comment: I have not been customizing the ISO at all. I just use Rufus to make the install usb drive. I want to customize Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (amd64)

Comment: want to customize after installation??

Comment: Before or after, I don't know if it matters, but I basically want the system to think that I am running "primeOS 1.0" instead of "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"

Comment: By the way, do they make cubic for windows10?